# Hover Over pop up that displays text

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover

I need some suggestions on what I can use for a text pop up that appears when mouse is hovered over certain text.
I have researched many webpages but nothing that I am looking for to be more specific,
I have a table with headers at the top.
I want people to hover over the heading and get a pop up with the definition of the header.
I have currently something working and its kind of simple.
What I was also wondering if there was a way to have the definitions read from a different place?
The definitions will be read from different pages, if I keep it the way that appears now I will have to change the definitions in many pages instead of one centralized place.
Not sure if this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a tooltip.  One of my favorites is the one in the Jquery ui toolkit.

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use default HTML tooltips (title property of the div markup)

```
<div title="My tooltip text">Header</div>
```